# Preferences always returns default value

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

This code I use to create value in SharedPreference.

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("user", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("ans1",1).commit();
```

Here is the code to get value from SharedPreference.

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("user", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
int ans = sharedpreferences.getInt("ans1",7);
```

Value of ans always is 7.

Comment: More details. Deal with database?

Comment: @ k_b : Is it compulsary to use private preference? You can use default one also..!!

Comment: Not possible! Try to replace ApplicationContext with your Activity's context!

Comment: Thanks, I replaced ApplicationContext and it works correctly.